# SQLAlchemy-Migrate or Alembic deletes data when renaming model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am using SQLAlchemy-Migrate to manage migrations for my PostgreSQL database. I changed the `__tablename__` for a model, and running the migration changed the name in the database, but all the rows in the table were deleted. How can I rename a model without deleting data?

```
class Contract(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contract'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_valid = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=IS_VALID)
```

I rename it from `contract` to `contracts` and get this migration:

```
def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    pre_meta.tables['contract'].drop()
    post_meta.tables['contracts'].create()
```

It drops the old table and creates a new one. I never examined other migration scripts because they always ran without dropping the data.

Comment: Please include your (relevant) definitions, both before and after your changes, and the migrations you've used. In other words produce a [mcve]. It sounds like you've tried assigning a new value to a model class' `__tablename__` attribute in a live system after the class has been constructed. As you've figured out, this will not work because the corresponding `Table` object is constructed by Declarative during class construction. Renaming a table in Postgresql is simple, and does not require dropping anything: `ALTER TABLE the_table RENAME TO another_table;`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SQLAlchemy-Migrate does not know that the table named "contract" in the database is the same as the model named "contracts" in the code. They're different names, and it only does a simple comparison. This is why you *always* review the generated migration scripts to make sure they do the right thing.

From the [SQLAlchemy-Migrate docs](https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changeset.html#table-rename), rename a table with the `rename` method.

```
pre_meta.tables['contract'].rename('contracts')
```

---

If you're using Alembic (or Flask-Alembic, or Flask-Migrate)  instead of SQLAlchemy-Migrate, the same thing happens. Use the [`rename_table`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.rename_table) method.

```
op.rename_table('contract', 'contracts')
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, for some readon, when using

```
op.rename_table("old_name", "new_name")
```

I kept getting

> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "new_name" already exists

In the end, I used

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    # op.drop_table('uploaded_resource')
    op.drop_table('sessions')
    
    op.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_name')
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME TO new_name')
    op.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE old_name_id_seq RENAME TO new_name_id_seq')
    op.execute('ALTER INDEX old_name_pkey RENAME TO new_name_pkey')
    ....
```

and

```
def downgrade():
    ...
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE new_name RENAME TO old_name')
    op.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE new_name_id_seq RENAME TO old_name_id_seq')
    op.execute('ALTER INDEX new_name_pkey RENAME TO old_name_pkey')
```

Which is less then ideal.

This also helped a fair bit
https://petegraham.co.uk/rename-postgres-table-with-alembic/

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @davidism's answer, when using the `op.rename_table()` function, you should make sure to add the relevant downgrade code in as well.

For example:
If you have `op.rename_table('table_name', 'new_table_name')` inside of your `upgrade()` function, then you need to include `op.rename_table('new_table_name', 'table_name')` inside of the `downgrade()` function just in case anything goes wrong.

Hope this helps anyone that sees this, seeing that this is an old question already.